# Aruch Hashulchan on municipality water for a mikvah

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, mikvah-ritual-bath, aruch-hashulchan

According to [this](https://www.jewishideas.org/article/use-municipal-city-water-mikveh-and-case-study-seattle-rabbinate-1950s) article, Aruch Hashulchan allowed municipality water to be used for a mikvah. Below is the direct quote from the article. Where can this Aruch Hashulchan be found?

> In the late 19th century, Rabbi Yehiel Michel Epstein (1829-1908), author of Arukh Hashulhan, declared unequivocally that water supplied from a system of pipes that channel water from a river to houses throughout a city can be used for a mikveh, provided that either the tube that feeds into the mikveh is affixed to the ground, or that the final three handbredths of that tube where it pours into the cistern is made out of a material that is not succeptible to tumah, such as wood.

Comment: I have a book by Rabbi David Miller on mikva in ur own house very interesting read.

Comment: And the tap needs to be shut so does not mimic a spring

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aruch Hashulchan YD 201:169

ויש מקוות בערים הגדולות שבשם הולכים המים מהנהרות לכל בתי העיר דרך צנורות וסלונות תחת הקרקע בעומק ונקרא בלשון המדינה וואד"א פראוואדי"ן וממשיכין גם למקואות המים האלו צריכים ליזהר או שיפלו למקוה מהצנורות והסילונות של ברזל המחוברים לקרקע או שקודם המקוה יעשו קצת סילון של עץ במשך ג' טפחים כמ"ש בסעי' קס"ד ובמים האלו מוכרחים לסגור המים אחרי הכנסם למקוה ולכן אין עליהם דין מעיין רק דין מקוה לטהר באשבורן ולא בזוחלים וצריכים ליזהר בכל זה שבארנו:

Comment: Thank you! (15)